# How to add a footer view in recyclerview that is get data from DB and in a reverse layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

currently i have a recyclerview that is populated from a database. also recyclerview setreverselayout == true for start item from the bottom. now i want to add a footer view to my recyclerview. i have tried some tutorials but still didnt get a working solution. any help will be really appreciated.

this is my adapter class

```
package com.shan.vehicle_maintainance;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class HistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryAdapter.HistoryViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    boolean isInserted;
    private List<History> listhistory;
    private DatabaseHelper myDb;
    public HistoryAdapter(Context context, List<History> listhistory) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listhistory = listhistory;
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    @Override
    public HistoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.history_list_layout, parent, false);
        return new HistoryViewHolder(view);
    }

    private void changeStateOfItemsInLayout(History historyItem, int p) {
        for (int x = 0; x < listhistory.size(); x++) {
            if (x == p) {
                historyItem.setShouldBeExpanded(true);
                //Since this is the tapped item, we will skip
                //the rest of loop for this item and set it expanded
                continue;
            }
            listhistory.get(x).setShouldBeExpanded(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final HistoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final History singleHistory = listhistory.get(position);
        holder.txt1.setText(singleHistory.getTxt1());
        holder.txt2.setText(String.valueOf(singleHistory.getTxt2())+" km");
        holder.txt3.setText("Rs."+String.valueOf(singleHistory.getTxt4()));
        String datettime = singleHistory.getTxt3();
        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = dt.parse(datettime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        History historyItem = listhistory.get(position);
        if(historyItem.getShouldBeExpanded()){
            expand(holder.expand);
            holder.mainview.setBackgroundResource(0);
        }else{
            collapse(holder.expand);

            //holder.expand2.collapse();
            final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                holder.mainview.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.cardview_bg) );
            } else {
                holder.mainview.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.cardview_bg));
            }
        }

        // *** same for the format String below
        SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
        holder.txt4.setText(dt1.format(date));

        //View v = holder.layoutManager.findViewByPosition(position)

        int size = listhistory.size() - 1;

        Integer tbltype = singleHistory.getTxt5();
        if (tbltype == 1){
            if (size == position){
                holder.historyimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.fuelhome6top);
            }else
                holder.historyimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.fuelhome6);
        }else if (tbltype == 2){
            if (size == position){
                holder.historyimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.expensehome6top);
            }else
                holder.historyimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.expensehome6);
        }else if (tbltype == 3){
            if (size == position){
                holder.historyimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.servicehome6top);
            }else
                holder.historyimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.servicehome6);
        }

        //holder.expand.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.expand.isShown()){

                    listhistory.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).setShouldBeExpanded(false);
                    //holder.expand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                    collapse(holder.expand);
//
//                    //holder.expand2.collapse();
//                    final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
//                    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
//                        holder.mainview.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.cardview_bg) );
//                    } else {
//                        holder.mainview.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.cardview_bg));
//                    }
                    //holder.expand2.collapse();
                    // holder.expand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //holder.expand2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    listhistory.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).setShouldBeExpanded(true);
                    changeStateOfItemsInLayout(listhistory.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()),holder.getLayoutPosition());
                    // holder.expand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //holder.expand2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //holder.expand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //expand(holder.expand);
                    //holder.mainview.setBackgroundResource(0);

                    //holder.expand2.expand();
                    //holder.expand2.expand();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //listhistory.get(position).getId();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("id", listhistory.get(position).getId());
                Integer tbltype = listhistory.get(position).getTxt5();

                if (tbltype == 1){
                    VehicleHome vehicleHome = (VehicleHome) v.getContext();
                    AddRefuelFrag addRefuelFrag = new AddRefuelFrag();
                    addRefuelFrag.setArguments(args);
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction_view_refuel = vehicleHome.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction_view_refuel.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                    fragmentTransaction_view_refuel.replace(R.id.activity_to_do, addRefuelFrag);
                    fragmentTransaction_view_refuel.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction_view_refuel.commit();
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "edit clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer tbltype = listhistory.get(position).getTxt5();

                if (tbltype == 1){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("Delete");
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    isInserted = myDb.deleteDataRefuel(String.valueOf(listhistory.get(position).getId()));
                                    if (isInserted == true) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context,"item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        VehicleHome vehicleHome = (VehicleHome) context;
                                        HistoryFrg historyFrg = new HistoryFrg();
                                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction_history = vehicleHome.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                        fragmentTransaction_history.replace(R.id.activity_to_do,historyFrg);
                                        //fragmentTransaction_refueling.addToBackStack(null);
                                        fragmentTransaction_history.commit();
                                    }else
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "cannot delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("id", listhistory.get(position).getId());
                Integer tbltype = listhistory.get(position).getTxt5();

                if (tbltype == 1){
                    VehicleHome vehicleHome = (VehicleHome) v.getContext();
                    RefuelItemViewFrag refuelItemViewFrag = new RefuelItemViewFrag();
                    refuelItemViewFrag.setArguments(args);
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction_view_refuel = vehicleHome.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction_view_refuel.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                    fragmentTransaction_view_refuel.replace(R.id.activity_to_do, refuelItemViewFrag);
                    fragmentTransaction_view_refuel.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction_view_refuel.commit();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public static void expand(View view) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

        ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(view, 0, view.getMeasuredHeight());
        mAnimator.start();
    }


    public static void collapse(final View view) {
        int finalHeight = view.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(view, finalHeight, 0);

        mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        mAnimator.start();
    }


    private static ValueAnimator slideAnimator(final View v, int start, int end) {

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = v.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = value;
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listhistory.size();
    }


    public class HistoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txt1;
        public TextView txt2;
        public TextView txt3;
        public TextView txt4;
        public ImageView historyimg;
        LinearLayout mainview;
        ImageButton edit,delete,view;
        //public ExpandableLayout expand,expand2;
        //public ExpandableRelativeLayout expand,expand2;
        LinearLayout expand;
        public HistoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            txt2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            txt3 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
            txt4 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt4);
            historyimg = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imghistory);
            //expand = (ExpandableLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand);
            //expand2 = (ExpandableLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand2);
            mainview = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainview);
            expand = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand);
            edit = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnedit);
            delete = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btndelete);
            view = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnview);


        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a footer view in recyclerView you have to return the size of data, the recyclerView have to populate, + 1 from the getItemCount() method.

```
public int getItemCount() {
 return listhistory.size() + 1;
}
```

Create a new viewHolder for the footer view and populate it with the appropriate footer layout that you have created.

Override the method getItemViewType(int position) to return an integer specific to each viewType

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 if (position == listhistory.size()) {
  return 0;
 } else {
  return 1;
 }
}
```

Change your onCreateViewHolder method to return appropriate viewHolder based on viewType;

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == 1) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.history_list_layout, parent, false);
            return new HistoryViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == 0) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                    .inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, parent, false);

            return new FooterViewHolder(view);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Modify your onBindViewHolder() method so that it checks for the instance of the holder i.e., either HistoryViewHolder or FooterViewHolder and write the code accordingly.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 if (holder instanceof HistoryViewHolder) {
  HistoyViewHolder historyHolder = (HistoryViewHolder) holder;
  // All your existing code here and replace holder with history holder
 } else {
  // if you footer is static ignore this else part otherwise write the appropriate code
 }
```

Hope this helps...✌

Comment: it works but its showing as a header, i know that its because recycler view is in reverse order. so i have change position == listhistory.size() to position == 0. but now its crashing in this line.  " final History singleHistory = listhistory.get(position);" and this is the eror that shows " java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2 "

Comment: @ShanNirmala , For example, consider your data size to be 2. So you will have data for positions 0 & 1. Since the reverse layout is enabled you're setting view type to footer for position 0 in getItemViewType(int position) method and for positions 1 & 2 you're setting historyView. Hence the onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) method receives positions 1 & 2 for historyView. But the data indexes are 0 & 1. So you need to decrement you need to access data by decrementing position by 1 in onBindViewHolder method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an RecyclerView Decorator to achieve what you want, without touching your adapter.

Have a look at [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration). Tell me if you want some more info about its usage.

Comment: i have tried item decoration. but when no items in the list, it doesnt showing. i want to show the footer even there are no items.